# Query a distance matrix in a vectorised fashion

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

The general problem is to find the total distance traveling between each city in the list and then back to the first city, given a matrix of distances.

[An example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYvUC.jpg) of a distance matrix.

Below is a working solution for the problem, but I am not sure how to translate this into a vectorized solution. "matrix" is a pandas dataframe that contains the distance matrix, and cities is a list of cities.

```
import pandas as pd
def total_distance(matrix, cities):
    dist = matrix[cities[0]][cities[-1]]
    i = 0
    while i < len(cities)-1:
        dist += matrix[cities[i]][cities[i+1]]
        i+=1
    return dist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `df` is your distance matrix, then stack it first. Do this only once, because it's an expensive operation.

```
dfstacked = df.stack()
```

Next, compute the distance in a *vectorized* fashion:

```
dfstacked.loc[list(zip(cities, np.roll(cities, -1)))].sum()
```

---

MWE:

```
df
   A  B  C  D
A  0  5  5  3
B  5  0  5  2
C  5  5  0  4
D  3  2  4  0

cities = ['A', 'D', 'B']
dfstacked = df.stack()
```

```
dfstacked.loc[list(zip(cities, np.roll(cities, -1)))].sum()
10  # 3 + 2 + 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Drawing from coldspeed's nice answer, we can avoid having to stack by just indexing along both dimensions, before using [`numpy.trace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.trace.html).

```
np.trace(df.loc[cities, np.roll(cities, -1)])
```

This may be a bit faster, mileage varying with your input size of course.

**Demo**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (25, 25)))
cities = np.random.randint(0, 25, 10).tolist()

%timeit np.trace(df.loc[cities, np.roll(cities, -1)])
# 843 µs ± 27 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df.stack().loc[list(zip(cities, np.roll(cities, -1)))].sum()
# 4.01 ms ± 189 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit stacked = df.stack()
stacked.loc[list(zip(cities, np.roll(cities, -1)))].sum()
# 2.83 ms ± 7.79 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```